# Initialise Array with Constructor - Java

Tags: java, arrays, object, constructor

I have 2 classes: Product and Room.
I want the user to be able to say how big the array to be, with creating an Object Room and enter an int.

```
public class Room{
  private int n;
  private int count = 0;
  Product [] space = new Product[n];

public Room(int n){
  this.n = n;
}
```

Why doesnt the constructor create the array with the input n, I give him?
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: When creating array in field, you have to provide him a constant, not a variable. If you need to declare array of length N passed by constructor, do it in constructor like:

`Product [] space;` is the field

`public Room(int n) {this.n = n; space = new Product[n];}`

Comment: Why should it? You ___explicitly___ told him to initialize `space` with the default value of `n`. So the question is: why? Why do you do that and why don't use just initialize it inside the constructor?

Comment: Why do people downvote the question? Is it bad to be a newb at java and looking for answers, if you cant find the answer on the internet...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The array is initialized before the constructor body, when `n` is still `0` (by default), so it gets a `0` length.

You need to initialize it in the constructor's body :

```
public Room(int n){
    this.n = n;
    this.space = new Product[n];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just try

```
public Room(int n){
  this.n = n;
this.space = new Product[n];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need extra fields for that (**n** or **count**), just give the size, and init the Array in the constructor... the rest of information is inside of the array object itself (array.lenght etc )

```
public class Room{

  Product [] space;
  public Room(int n){
      space = new Product[n]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the array *inside* the constructor.

```
public Room(int n) {
    this.n = n;
    this.space = new Product[n];
}
```

Otherwise, when you're doing it outside, `n` has a default value of `0` and the array created is also of size `0`. Basically useless.